# Live Internet Audio Stream --> Smart Outlet Manipulation... Is It Possible?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, ifttt, internet-radio

I've been trying to think of a solution to this idea for ages, and after several bouts of research I'm still pretty clueless.

I run [a college radio station with an online stream](http://arouseosu.com) (in mp3 and m3u). We have over 100 DJs and from time to time, the stream will go out without the DJ realizing (until someone tells them, which could be an hour late or worse).

My dream would be to run some kind of script to check our audio stream every minute or so that registers whether it receives a null value, then use something (like IFTTT?) to send that information to a smart outlet within the studio, where our ON AIR sign would either be on or off, depending.

Is this possible? Impossible? Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are generally about a specific programming problem, and it is generally expected that askers make an attempt to create a solution to their problem before asking a question. This is not a site where people solve your problems for you. For more information on what topics you can ask here, check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Check out NodePing... they have an audio monitoring service, and can alert you when things go down.  https://nodeping.com/  What's the source of the downtime?  Is it just dead air with a DJ not knowing how to operate the studio?  Or, is the encoder losing a connection?  Server going offline?